# Call macro from custom button in Ribbon

Tags: vba, excel

The following macro runs ok, when called from `Developer -> Macros - Macro1`

```
Sub Macro1()

ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "http://www.portal-gestao.com/financas.html"

End Sub
```

But, since I'm using a custom button in the Ribbon, I'm calling the macro like:

```
<button id="customButton4" label="Finanças"  onAction="Macro1" imageMso="HyperlinkInsert" />
```

Which is returning the error:

```
Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment
```

Basically, I want to open a web page when the user clicks a custom button on the ribbon. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify your macro to include this parameter:

```
Sub Macro1(control As IRibbonControl)
```

Comment: I did give you +1 but can you elaborate? Is that strictly necessary? I am looking at an Add-In I created in PPT and while several procedures take the control as a required argument, at least one of the procedures does **not**.

Comment: I believe the use of the Ribbon is slightly different for each of the Office applications. (IIRC for Access we need to create a table and store some XML in it.) Besides, PowerPoint VBA is.. odd.